# Copy and Paste from an Excel Spreadsheet to a ASP.NET Control

Tags: asp.net, excel, webforms, copy

I would like to be able to copy one row and five columns from an Excel spreadsheet to a table like structure on a ASP.NET web form.  The idea is keeping the data in the exact row and  column from Excel to the table like control on the ASP.NET web-form.  Then I want to be able to save to the contents of the ASP.NET control to a database by a buttoon command click.  What ASP.NET control would allow me to do this?  Gridviews and datagrids don't seem to allow me to do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen, you have to parse the content of the clipboard yourself (comma separated) and place that in the cells of the gridView.
I would like to know if there is an other way.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement exactly matches with mine and i found solution here. you can try tthis link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jebarson/archive/2010/06/29/copy-and-paste-excel-or-clipboard-data-to-gridview-in-asp-net.aspx if you need any help feel free to ask.

Comment: Link out of date